# How to add an if statement inside a for loop in VBA?

Tags: vba, for-loop

```
For a = 1 to 10
    if a = dumm then next a 'this statement should avoid running the subsequent codes if the if statement is true (similar to continue in c++
    end if
    'statements that need to run when the if statement is not true

next a
```

Why does this code not work?? It throws **compile error: Next without for**

Comment: get rid of next a, there needs to be an action in the if statement

Comment: `if a = dumm then a = a + 1`

Comment: `if a = dumm then goto... ` (this requires adding a label that you can use with the `goto` statement.

Comment: @mo.h if there is not next a the loop doesnt run 10 times

Comment: @DavidZemens that runs the remaining code. I do not want that.

Comment: why not? When you increment with the `Next` statement, the code will run on the subsequent iteration anyways. In any case, there's several obvious ways to do this, please see answer below.

Comment: @DavidZemens Also, I dont want to use a GOTO in my code. Any alternatives?

Comment: @DavidZemens running the remaining code on the subsequent iteration is fine, but I do NOT want to run that code if the condition satisfies.

Comment: Why not? The subsequent iteration is the *same* if you're incrementing loop variable `a`. It makes no difference on which pass the code executes (unless there is something very complicated about the executable statements, in which case, you probably should add more detail to your Question to clarify).

Comment: @DavidZemens Thank you very much. I did not think about that. That solves the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why does this code not work?? It throws compile error: Next without for

Because you have a `next` without a corresponding `For`.  `For/Next` and `For Each/Next` must be paired, you can't open a `For` loop without a `Next` and you can't use `Next` without `For.

Simply:

```
if a = dumm then a = a + 1
```

This increments your `a` value within the loop. I'm unclear as to why you think this isn't applicable, because whether you increment `a` and *then* run the code, or skip to the next `a` (which is functionally equivalent to incrementing it via `+1`), the result should be same

Or, you could add a label and a `GoTo` statement:

```
For a = 1 to 10
    if a = dumm then 
        GoTo MyLabel 
    end if
    'statements that need to run when the if statement is not true

MyLabel:
next a
```

Or, and my preference, just use proper boolean expressions:

```
For a = 1 to 10
    if not a = dumm Then
        'statements that need to run when the if statement is not true
    end if
Next
```

**If you don't want to continue the loop at all**, then either add an `Exit` statement,

```
For a = 1 to 10
    if a = dumm Then Exit For
    'statements that need to run when the if statement is not true

Next
```

or use a `Do/While` loop with proper escape conditions:

```
a = 1
Do 
    'statements go here...    
    a = a + 1
Loop While a <= 10 and Not a = dumm
```